# Controller in my MVC project returning null from Ajax Post call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure to why the controller is receiving a data from an Ajax call . Could i  be doing anything wrong?

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Product/UpdateDetails")]
        public ActionResult UpdateProduct (ProductModel model) <<// model here is null
        {
            Product p = new Product
            {
                ProductId = p.ProductId,
                Price = p.Price,

            };


            return View("_ProductDetail"); }
```

Ajax call below:

```
  var model = {
            ProductId: 1,
            Price: 270.99,

        };

        var json = JSON.stringify(model)


        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/UpdateDetails',
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            model: model,
            success: function (results) {

            }
        });


//Model 
public class Product
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public double Price {get;set;}
}
```

Can you guys spot anything that i may be doing wrong in the code above ? I can't see anything that i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just delete `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and `model: model,` and add `data: model`. (there is no need to stringify the data, but you were not using it anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/Product/UpdateDetails',
     type: 'Post',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: json,
     success: function (results) {

     }
});
```

You used `JSON.Stringify()` on your model, but forgot to use the variable `"json"` on the ajax call, so the ajax was trying to post a "non-json" model.

Also, there is no `model` setting in ajax calls, the correct one to post your data is `data`, as you can see [here](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-post/).